# HPROF Analyzer tool not found in Android studio 3

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-studio-3.0, hprof

HPROF Analyzer/Analyzer tasks is a great tool in android studio 2 which helps detect memory leaks. It's less time-consuming than using the eclipse MAT tool. However, I couldn't find it using the new Android Profiler in AS3.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find it?
I have the same issue.
The new memory profiles is sooooo slow. Its just unworkable. 
If i dump a heap. I don't get a hprof file out of it. Official documentation is still for android studio 2

Comment: Dump heap and then open the captures tab (top left below the project and structure tabs). Double click the hprof file and voila, you get the analyzer.

Comment: If you can't find the capture file, check mark's comment below.

Comment: Yeah i found it. I did not know you had to save it as a .hprof file and still convert it command line with 
hprof-conv dump.hprof realhprofdump.hprof

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to save the dump file and open it via the "capture" tab. Then the analyzer is available

Comment: Interestingly I found that AS was not showing the saved capture in the project explorer window, or nothing in the captures window even after saving hprof file.  I went into Preferences -> Editor -> File Types and found under Ignore files and folders the *.hprof file type. I removed this, then it appeared in Project Explorer.

Comment: In my case file was exported without extension. add ".hprof" and everything should be fine

Answer (score 3):

First save your .hprof file.

[image]

Then drag that into Android Studio.

Find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler.html#save_the_heap_dump_as_hprof)

Comment: The section part of your "find more details" link isn't valid any more.  Better link: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#save-hprof

Comment: Android Studio 3.0.1 saves the file with nothing in it, size of the file 0kb